# Jquery tooltip that follows mouse

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'd like to simply have a tooltip that follows the mouse when it is hovered over a div. I'd like to use this one:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/

And i have it working, however i can't get the tooltip to actually follow the mouse when the mouse pointer moves. I know that sounds like stupid question but their site doesn't have any demo of this functionality so i'm left wondering if it is supported. Would anyone know how to make this work? Thanks for your input and time!

Comment: resolve this question?

Answer (score 9):

I'd found [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html) on their site.

I would make my own.. just to help you out little:

```
<style>
    .item {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        top: 200px;
        left: 400px;
        background: #CCC;
    }

    .item .tooltip {
        position: fixed; /** depends on how it handles the e.pageX and e.pageY **/
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #06F;
        z-index: 10;
        display: none; /**let the tooltip be not visable, when startup **/
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".item").mousemove(function(e) { 
            // put other effects in when moving over the element
            // from e you can get the pageX(left position) and pageY(top position) 
            // im not sure if it was the relative or the absolute position
            // i added 10 pxs on the top and left to show the tooltip a bit after
            $('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 10)
                .css('top', e.pageY + 10)
                .css('display', 'block');

            // or in a simpler way:
            $('.tooltip').css({
                left: e.pageX + 10,
                top: e.pageY + 10
            }).css('display', 'block');
        });

        $(".item").mouseout(function() { 
            $('.tooltip').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="item">
    <p>This is my item</p>
    <div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
</div>
```

If I were you make your own tooltip but it's up to you what you want.

### UPDATE

Of 3 years later...
And of course, nowadays you should add a `debounce` or `throttle`.

Answer (score 5):

w.r.t. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/dynamic.htm, try

```
// initialize tooltip
$("#dyna img[title]").tooltip({

   // tweak the position
   offset: [10, 2],

   // use the "slide" effect
   effect: 'slide'

// add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
}).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } })

// Additional code : BEGIN
.mousemove(function(evt) {$(".tooltip").css({
    left:(evt.pageX - $.tools.tooltip.conf.offset[1]),
    top:(evt.pageY - $.tools.tooltip.conf.offset[0])
});})
// Additional code : END

;
```

Please tweak the positioning yourself. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the example on their website you could turn this

```
<script>
$("#demo img[title]").tooltip();
</script>
```

into this

```
<script>
$("#demo img[title]").tooltip();
$(".tooltip").css('position','absolute');
$("#demo").mousemove(function(e) {
    var x_offset = -100;
    var y_offset = -130;
    $('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + x_offset).css('top', e.pageY + y_offset);
});
</script>
```

This uses the jQuery [mousemove event](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) and [mouse positioning information](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position).  The CSS `position` of the tooltip is set to `absolute` so it will properly follow the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a plugin called TrackStar that does exactly this.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TrackStar

Answer (score 2):

Set option **track** to **true**:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ track: true });
```

[JQuery API, tooltip widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-track)